# Multiply and groupby pandas python AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'mul' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Tags: python, pandas

df

```
Person           Mul col
 A                   0
 B                   1 
 B                   1
 A                   0
```

I want to groupby on Person and find the multiplication of Mul col using groupby

Tried:

```
 df.groupby('Person')['Mul col'].mul()
```

Error

AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'mul' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: Hi of course. Actually stack overflow didnt allow me to accept answer without waiting for 10 min, hence could not upvote and later i had signed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prod` instead:

```
df.groupby('Person', as_index=False)['Mulcol'].prod()

     Person  Mulcol
0      A       0
1      B       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic Syntax:

```
>>>df.groupby([col_name]).prod()
```

Acc To your Code:

```
>>>df.groupby(['Person']).prod() # it will return dataframe from which we extract required col
```